# How to structure mysql database for use with sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to make a database of products that can be searched by many facets(like newegg or amazon). At first I was going to try to do the whole thing with mysql but further research has led me to believe that is a bad idea so instead I am thinking about using Sphinx.

My question is how would I set up the mysql tables for this? Would I just have one table for the products and another one with all the facets that would just have a couple large varchar fields and foreign key to the product?

Comment: Judging from the lack of response, maybe I shouldn't be using sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a huge Sphinx expert, but I'd say that you don't have to stick all your data in one table. Sphinx can handle associations just fine. If you are planning to use Rails for your front-end then take a look at thinking_sphinx gem. It definitely allows you to specify attributes based on data spread out into many tables. In my experience I didn't have to change my data structure to accommodate Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

I'll pipe in.

You don't really need to actually. Facets in Sphinx are just ID's (at least in 0.9.9 the current stable release). I am going to assume that you have a standard product table with your different facets stored as foreign keys to other tables.

So assuming you have this you can just select over the main product table and set up the facets in sphinx as per the documentation.

I would really need to see your table structure to comment further. It sounds like you have your products spread over multiple tables. In this case as you mentioned I would go with a single table which you index on which is populated with the contents of all the others.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Sphinx is that you can use a MySQL query to get your data into Sphinx.  This allows you to structure your database in a way that's optimized for your business logic, without having to worry about how search will perform.  As long as you're creative with the query you write for `sql_query`, you can normalize your database however you'd like, and still be able to grab all the text to be indexed with a single query.  For example, if you need to get strings from a many-to-one relationship into your index, you can do so using a subquery.

```
sql_query = SELECT *, (SELECT pa.text FROM products_attr pa WHERE pa.product_id=p.id ) \
               FROM products p;
```

Additionally, if you drop downs where you search on attribute IDs, you use Sphinx's `multi-value attribute`.  This way, you can search by attribute ID, as well as the text of the attrbute.

```
sql_attr_multi  = uint attributes from query; \  
  SELECT product_id AS id, id AS attribute FROM product_attributes ;
```